# Still me... Sending a HID Descriptor results in a USBD_STATUS_CANCELED (0xc001000) error

Tags: usb, usb-device, usb-host

I am developping a USB HID Device on a STM32F7 microcontroller.

When plugging the device to the host (Windows 10 computer), everything is going well until the host sends a **GET_HID_REPORT_DESCRIPTOR** request. My device replies with the report descriptor (I've checked on Wireshark & USB Analyzer that the data sent were the expected ones), but the host does not accepts it and keeps sending **GET_HID_REPORT_DESCRIPTOR** requests.

When analyzing the transactions on the bus, I've found that the transaction when sending this descriptor results in a **USBD_STATUS_CANCELED (0xc001000)** error (see picture below):

[image]

I've searched for this error on the internet but I have not found any information who could explain the cause of it.

Thank you for any help.

**EDIT:** the problem was a timing problem, my device replies to the host 5 seconds after receiving its request. Refucing this delay solved the problem.

Comment: It looks like there are 5 seconds between the request and the cancellation. So it could be that Windows aborts/cancels the request after that period.

Comment: @Codo hello, thank you for your help. You are right, there is a problem with my timings, I've solved it and it works!

Comment: @Codo you Can post it as an answer so I Can validate it, if you want. Thank you again !

Comment: I don't think my hint is a helpful answer for other people. Why don't you write an answer yourself and provide more details as to why it took the device more than 5 seconds to answer.